# How to download old versions of plugins?

Tags: plugins, plugin-repository

I have previously been able to go the the plugin repository to locate previous versions of plugins in order to restore compromised websites. Since the design for the plugin repository has changed I can no longer find where they are stored.

I have scrolled down to the "Contributors & Developers" section then followed various links to try and download older versions but can only seem to download files that have had changes (not all files). Please if someone could help me out that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. I suggest you ask this question on WordPress's support section. You will get an answer there faster.

Comment: You may also be able to check old versions out of the subversion repositories under the developer links in the plugin pages - there should be a tag per version.

Answer (score 2):

For now you can use an SVN checkout from https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/

Please see: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/

(I've passed the suggestion to the WordPress meta team) Here's the ticket url: meta.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2365